# Why is my gradle effectively saying it doesn't exist?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to mod in minecraft and gradle is not working.
When I type in "./gradlew genSources", it says I'm using Java 8, when everything is set to Java 17. Then, when I type in "gradle --version", it comes up with this:

> gradle : The term 'gradle' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

Nothing in the tutorial I am following has covered the issue, I'm wondering why the program is telling me it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

try `./gradlew -version`. because you may not have gradle natively installed

Comment: Hey, I tried this command and it worked, showing a version. I then tried running the genSources command again, and it broke due to a different error this time. 

"Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap"